# Calculate then change form field value onselect

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has some field values pre-populated from a PHP query. I am trying to change the value of the AMOUNT field by adding $2.00 to the existing value if a selection made in field "os0" contains "XX" anywhere in the selected value. I am having trouble getting the javascript code correct to make this work, i think im using the DOM wrong but not sure. The remote URL is only receiving the value set by the PHP echo on submit, regardless of the option/value selected for field "os0". Any help please.

```
<form method="post" action="remote-url" name="ppal"> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$res[0]?>">
<input type="hidden" name="SKU" value="<?=$res[1]?>">
<select id="os0" name="on0" onChange="setval()">
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium/option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="XL">X-Large</option>
<option value="XXL">XXL</option>
<option value="XXXL">XXXL</option>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setval()
  {
  if (document.forms["ppal"].os0.value.indexOf("XX") > -1) {document.getElementById("amount") = document.getElementById("amount")+2};
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the script. First, it is calling `document.getElementById("amount")`, but there is no element with an ID "amount". You might want to change this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$res[0]?>">
```

to this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?=$res[0]?>">
```

Second, when the script calls `document.getElementById("amount")`, it gets a reference to the input element, not the value the user typed into the element. You'll need to use the `.value` property of the input element to get what the user typed. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp for more information about the `/value` property.

Keep in mind that the value property is a string, not a numeric, so you'll also have to convert using something like `parseInt()` before doing arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. I went back over the code and fixed what i missed on the ID attribute as well as the DOM needing to be pointed at VALUE. In order to get it to work I ultimately had to use parseFloat() on the value to get a valid decimal integer value. - Thanks again for pointing in the right direction.